# TypeError: first argument must be string or compiled pattern

Tags: python, mysql, csv

I am fetching values from a database table called blocked_sites. If the value of 0th attribute in the table blocked_sites is present the 19th or 26th field of the file items.csv, then that row of the csv is to be excluded from the csv file. I am writing a code for that and getting this error:

```
$ python csv_dupli_prev.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "csv_dupli_prev.py", line 48, in <module>
    found = re.search(row[0], row1[19])
  File "/home/debarati/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/re.py", line 182, in search
    return _compile(pattern, flags).search(string)
  File "/home/debarati/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/re.py", line 300, in _compile
    raise TypeError("first argument must be string or compiled pattern")
TypeError: first argument must be string or compiled pattern
```

The code is as follows:

```
connection = pymysql.connect (host = "localhost", user = "root", passwd = "......", db = "city_details")          
cursor = connection.cursor ()
csv_file = csv.reader(open("items.csv", "r"))
newrows = []
cursor.execute ("select * from blocked_sites")
data4 = cursor.fetchall ()
for row in data4:
   for row1 in csv_file:
      str1 = row1[19]
      str2 = row1[26]
      found = re.search(row[0], str1)
      found1 = re.search(row[0], str2)
      if found==None and found1==None and row1 not in newrows:
         newrows.append(row1)
writer = csv.writer(open("items.csv", "w"))
writer.writerows(newrows)
```

Comment: Judging only from the error message (thanks for including the whole of it - not everyone does that), `row[0]` is not a string or compiled pattern. Look at it in the debugger or with a `print` statement to see what it is.

Comment: @ArndtJonasson : I found the bug and fixed it. Check my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the following line in my code:

```
cursor.execute ("select * from blocked_sites")
```

to this:

```
cursor.execute ("select content from blocked_sites")
```

and the bug got fixed.